# Unload the jdbc sql server drivers

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, drivers

I load JDBC SQL Server drivers to connect to a database after the whole process I want to unload all the registered drivers

To register the drivers I use

```
  static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I deregister all these drivers?

I tried the following but it seems not to be working

```
 Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while(drivers.nextElement() != null){
        Driver d = drivers.nextElement();
        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get the following exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Vector Enumeration
```

**Edit**

Now I get the following error when I run another task which also needs a connection to database using JDBC

```
 WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : Native Library C:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

any idea?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "it seems not to be working"?

Comment: Have a look at the edit

Comment: Use `while(drivers.hasMoreElements()) { ... } ` to iterate thru an Enumeration

Comment: Just figured it out thanks let me check if it works

Comment: It means the class is still loaded

Comment: You probably try to unload the driver with another class loader, that it was loaded. Try to java.sql.DriverManager.setLogWriter(PrintWriter) on the beginning - it could provide some info.

Comment: In the above code all the three drivers are loaded but DriverManger.getDrivers() return me only JdbcOdbcDriver

Comment: Have you tried to setting log writer to DriverManager? Has it printed anything?

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure there's an element with `hasMoreElements()` before using it with `nextElement()`.

See also the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html